SIGSTOP to process with audio, prevent audio server from stopping
When I send a SIGSTOP signal to a specific game (as some sort of pause, SIGTSTP is ignored), it stops audio completely for the whole system, only resuming after I send SIGCONT to the same process. My audio server is "PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.0.6)". I am looking for some insight on why that happens, and if possible, a way to mitigate this. It seems that this behaviour depends on the process, for example, this doesn't happen with another game I tried the same thing.
